# How do I correct a python clound function cve analyzer error?

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have a google cloud function that is not correctly creating a file per request, at one time it worked fine but no longer seems to create a file or function properly.  It is a python function designed to analyze CVE severity.

```
import requests
import json
import csv
import os
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from google.cloud import storage

CUSTOMERS = ["test"]
QUERY = 'has_prefix(resourceUrl, "https://www.googleapis.com/compute")'
CVE_SEVERITY_URL = "https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/{}"


def entrypoint(request):
    slack_url = os.environ['URL']
    headers = {"Content-type": "application/json"}
    try:
        client = storage.Client()
        bucket = client.get_bucket(os.environ['BUCKET'])
        key = generate_token()
        cve_data_today = get_cve_data_today(key)
        analyze_tday_and_yday_cve_data(cve_data_today, bucket)
        upload_cve_data_today(cve_data_today, bucket)
    except Exception as err:
        print(err)
        requests.post(url=slack_url, headers=headers, data=str({"text": f"Found exception: {err}"}))
    return "Done"


def generate_token():
    token_headers = {'Metadata-Flavor': 'Google'}
    token_url = os.environ['METADATA_URL'] + os.environ['FUNCTION_URL']
    token_response = requests.get(token_url, headers=token_headers)
    token = json.loads(token_response.text)['access_token']
    return token


def get_cve_data_today(key):
    all_data = []
    cves = dict()
    for customer in CUSTOMERS:
        url = f"https://containeranalysis.googleapis.com/v1/projects/{customer}/occurrences?filter={QUERY}"
        headers = {
            "Authorization": f"Bearer {key}",
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
        while True:
            response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
            info = json.loads(response.text)
            for item in info.get("occurrences", []):
                if (
                    "upgrade" in item
                    and "distribution" in item["upgrade"]
                    and "cve" in item["upgrade"]["distribution"]
                ):
                    vm_name = item["resourceUri"].rsplit("/", 1)[-1]
                    package = item["upgrade"]["package"]
                    version = item["upgrade"]["parsedVersion"]["fullName"]
                    #create_time = item["createTime"]
                    cve = item["upgrade"]["distribution"]["cve"]
                    for c in cve:
                        cves[c] = None
                    data = {
                        "customer": customer,
                        "vm_name": vm_name,
                        "package": package,
                        "version": version,
                        #"create_time": create_time,
                        "cve": cve,
                    }
                    all_data.append(data)
            token = info.get("nextPageToken")
            if not token:
                break
            url = f"https://containeranalysis.googleapis.com/v1/projects/{customer}/occurrences?filter={QUERY}&pageToken={token}"
    
    for cve in cves.keys():
        cve_url = CVE_SEVERITY_URL.format(cve)
        result = requests.get(cve_url)
        if not result.status_code == 200:
            raise Exception(f"Could not grab necessary details from cve website for {cve}")
        soup = BeautifulSoup(result.text, "html.parser")
        row = soup.find("span", {"class": "severityDetail"})
        if row:
            cves[cve] = row.findAll("a")[0].text
        else:
            cves[cve] = None
            print(f"{cve} does not exist in NVD")

    all_cve_info = []
    for d in all_data:
        for cve in d["cve"]:
            if cves[cve]:
                data = [d["customer"], d["vm_name"], d["package"], d["version"], cve, cves[cve]]
                all_cve_info.append(",".join(data))
    
    return all_cve_info


def analyze_tday_and_yday_cve_data(cve_data_today, bucket):
    yday = (datetime.today()-timedelta(days=1)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    yday_filename = "cve-info_{}.csv".format(yday)
    yday_filepath = "/tmp/{}".format(yday_filename)

    blob = storage.Blob(yday_filename, bucket)
    blob.download_to_filename(yday_filepath)

    blob = storage.Blob("cve-info_yesterday.csv", bucket)
    blob.upload_from_filename(yday_filepath)

    with open(yday_filepath, "r") as yf:
        yday_file = yf.readlines()
    
    yday_stripped_file = [i.rstrip("\n") for i in yday_file]
    url = os.environ['URL']
    headers = {"Content-type": "application/json"}
    
    found_cve = []
    for line in cve_data_today:
        if line not in yday_stripped_file:
            found_cve.append(line)
    print(found_cve)

    if found_cve:
        cve_count = dict()
        for record in found_cve:
            result = record.split(",")[-1]
            if result not in cve_count:
                cve_count[result] = 0
            cve_count[result] += 1
        
        sorted_cve_count = sorted(cve_count.items(), key=lambda x:x[0], reverse=True)
        sorted_output = [i[0]+': '+str(i[1]) for i in sorted_cve_count]
        output = ",".join(sorted_output).replace(",","\n")
        
        data = str({"blocks": [{"type": "section", "text": {"type": "mrkdwn", "text": "*VM Analysis Report*"}},
                               {"type": "section", "text": {"type": "mrkdwn", "text": "*New CVEs found today!!* Summary:"}},
                               {"type": "section", "text": {"type": "mrkdwn", "text": output}},
                               {"type": "section", "text": {"type": "mrkdwn", "text": f"*Total new CVEs*: {len(found_cve)}"}},
                               {"type": "section", "text": {"type": "mrkdwn", "text": f"*Data Studio link to CVE report*: <https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/xxxxxxxxxxxxx/page/kmqAC|View Report>"}},
                               {"type": "divider"}]})
        requests.post(url=url, headers=headers, data=data)
    else:
        data = str({"text": "No new CVE found today in VM analysis report"}) 
        requests.post(url=url, headers=headers, data=data)


def upload_cve_data_today(cve_data_today, bucket):
    tday_filename = "cve-info_{}.csv".format(datetime.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
    tday_filepath = "/tmp/{}".format(tday_filename)

    with open(tday_filepath, "w", newline="") as tf:
        writer = csv.writer(tf)
        writer.writerow(
            [
                "CUSTOMER",
                "VM_NAME",
                "PACKAGE",
                "VERSION",
                #"CREATE_TIME",
                "CVE",
                "SEVERITY",
            ]
        )
        for d in cve_data_today:
            data = d.split(',')
            writer.writerow(data)
    
    blob = storage.Blob(tday_filename, bucket)
    blob.upload_from_filename(tday_filepath)

    blob = storage.Blob("cve-info_today.csv", bucket)
    blob.upload_from_filename(tday_filepath)

    print("cve data for today successfully pushed to bucket")
```

The error that comes up is the file is not created and when the function goes to search for the file it is not present and gives an error.

[Edit]To add a bit of information, the last time the report was created successfully was 30 days ago, nothing has changed with the code, and the error that is created is simply that the report does not exist, because it was never created.

To add some logs for context

```
2022-08-30T06:00:01.175333294Zcve-analyzercgvsmsormatt Function execution started
Function execution started
Default
2022-08-30T06:00:53.465496Zcve-analyzercgvsmsormatt CVE-2022-1271 does not exist in NVD
CVE-2022-1271 does not exist in NVD
Default
2022-08-30T06:01:07.723597Zcve-analyzercgvsmsormatt 404 GET https://storage.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/sl-cve-reports/o/cve-info_2022-08-29.csv?alt=media: No such object: sl-cve-reports/cve-info_2022-08-29.csv: ('Request failed with status code', 404, 'Expected one of', <HTTPStatus.OK: 200>, <HTTPStatus.PARTIAL_CONTENT: 206>)
404 GET https://storage.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/sl-cve-reports/o/cve-info_2022-08-29.csv?alt=media: No such object: sl-cve-reports/cve-info_2022-08-29.csv: ('Request failed with status code', 404, 'Expected one of', <HTTPStatus.OK: 200>, <HTTPStatus.PARTIAL_CONTENT: 206>)
Debug
2022-08-30T06:01:07.953438449Zcve-analyzercgvsmsormatt Function execution took 66778 ms. Finished with status code: 200
Function execution took 66778 ms. Finished with status code: 200
Error
2022-08-30T15:46:06.156512044ZCloud FunctionsGetFunctionus-west2:cve-analyzertravis.markley@supportlogic.io {@type: type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog, authenticationInfo: {…}, authorizationInfo: […], methodName: google.cloud.functions.v2.FunctionService.GetFunction, request: {…}, requestMetadata: {…}, resourceLocation: {…}, resourceName: projects/test/locations/us-west2/functions/cv…
{@type: type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog, authenticationInfo: {…}, authorizationInfo: […], methodName: google.cloud.functions.v2.FunctionService.GetFunction, request: {…}, requestMetadata: {…}, resourceLocation: {…}, resourceName: projects/test/locations/us-west2/functions/cv…
Info
2022-08-30T15:46:06.206030ZCloud FunctionsGetFunctionus-west2:cve-analyzertravis.markley@supportlogic.io {@type: type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog, authenticationInfo: {…}, authorizationInfo: […], methodName: google.cloud.functions.v1.CloudFunctionsService.GetFunction, request: {…}, requestMetadata: {…}, resourceLocation: {…}, resourceName: projects/test/locations/us-west2/functi…
{@type: type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog, authenticationInfo: {…}, authorizationInfo: […], methodName: google.cloud.functions.v1.CloudFunctionsService.GetFunction, request: {…}, requestMetadata: {…}, resourceLocation: {…}, resourceName: projects/test/locations/us-west2/functi…
Info
2022-08-30T15:46:06.402733ZCloud FunctionsGenerateDownloadUrlus-west2:cve-analyzertravis.markley@supportlogic.io {@type: type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog, authenticationInfo: {…}, authorizationInfo: […], methodName: google.cloud.functions.v1.CloudFunctionsService.GenerateDownloadUrl, request: {…}, requestMetadata: {…}, resourceLocation: {…}, resourceName: projects/test/locations/us-west…
{@type: type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog, authenticationInfo: {…}, authorizationInfo: […], methodName: google.cloud.functions.v1.CloudFunctionsService.GenerateDownloadUrl, request: {…}, requestMetadata: {…}, resourceLocation: {…}, resourceName: projects/test/locations/us-west…
```

Comment: Your question would benefit from logging and other debugging information. Absent those, we're left to try to run through your code in its entirety ourselves to try to determine what's going wrong. It would be helpful if you include the error messages and an analysis of what's working (specific CVEs, specific files etc.) and what isn't.

Comment: "At one time it worked" is unhelpful. When did it last work? What's changed since then? What have you done to try to determine what's changed? Possibilities include you changed something, you've changed permissions, you've exceeded quota etc.

Comment: Google provides client libraries for its services including a [Python library for Container Analysis](https://cloud.google.com/container-analysis/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-python). Your code would benefit from using this client library rather than creating an HTTP client from scratch.

Comment: Unfortunately this is an example of taking over something already pre-built.  I would love to use something not hand built from scratch.

Comment: I'll find some time this afternoon to try the code and investigate

Comment: I don't understand `generate_token`. I don't understand what value your code uses for `METADATA_URL` but assume (!?) it's trying to get an identity token (using `audience={FUNCTION_URL}`) and I don't understand how that would (ever have) work(ed). The code handcrafts (to my chagrin!) the request against Container Analysis service and that service requires an `access_token`.

Comment: Have a look at this version of [`generate_token`](https://gist.github.com/DazWilkin/57865536934e2f31981c48b12175f4e1)